# sprites not appearing when canvas loads

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am currently working on a space invaders game. However, I have stumbled upon an issue, when my canvas loads the sprite that I want to appear does not show. I checked the path and it is correct. I even opened the inspector and it showed that the sprites file was there. Some of the functions such as `Sprite` are predefined in a file. I am completing this through a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IerQ5M9p4YY&t=1240s)

```js
 var screen, input, frames;
  var alSprite, taSprite, ciSprite;
  var aliens, dir, tank, bullets, cities;

  function main () {
   screen = new Screen(510, 600);
   input = new InputHandler();

   var img = new Image();
   img.addEventListener("load", function(){

    alSprite = [
    [new Sprite(this, 10, 10, 22, 15), new Sprite(this, 0, 16, 22, 16)],
    [new Sprite(this, 22, 16, 15), new Sprite(this, 22, 15, 16, 16)],
    [new Sprite(this, 38, 0, 24, 16), new Sprite(this, 38, 16, 24, 16)]

    ];
    taSprite = new Sprite(this);
    ciSprite = new Sprite(this);

    init();
    run();
   });
   img.src = "res/invaders.png";
  };

  function init() {};
  function run() {

   var loop = function(){
    update();
    render();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, screen.canvas);
   };
  };
  function update() {};
  function render() {

   screen.drawSprite(alSp[0][0], 10, 10);
  };
```

```css
canvas{
   background-color: #000;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   margin: auto;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/helper.js"></script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="main()">
</body>
</html>
```

I have also included the helper.js file.

```js
//Helper function

//Screen
function Screen(width, height){
 this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
 this.canvas.width = this.width = width;
 this.canvas.height = this.height = height;
 this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

 document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);

};

Screen.prototype.drawSprite = function(sp, x, y){
 this.ctx.drawImage(sp, img, sp.x, sp.y, sp.w, sp.h, x, y, sp.w, sp.h);


};
//Sprite
function Sprite(img, x, y, w, h){
 this.img = img;
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.w = w;
 this.h = h;

};


//InputHandler
function InputHandler() {
 this.down = {};
 this.pressed = {};

 var _this = this;
 document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt){
  _this.down[evt.keyCode];

 });
 document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt){
  delete _this.down[evt.keyCode];
  delete _this.pressed[evt.keyCode];

 });

};

InputHandler.prototype.isDown = function(code){
 return this.down[code];

};

InputHandler.prototype.isPressed = function(code){
 if(this.pressed[code]) {
  return false;
 } else if (this.down[code]) {
  return this.pressed[code] = true;
 }
 return false;

};
```

Comment: In cases like these always start by reducing the amount of code, focus only on the problem and remove everything else... can you upload the sprite somewhere?

Comment: Yes I will upload it to google drive and send you the link.

Comment: Here is the link to the sprites https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y3sYc3T4hinqvGBQ2bpqhytFv8aHCkTp?usp=sharing

Comment: drawSprite(alSp[0][0]... did you mean alSprite[0][0]? Then in drawSprite method, you do drawImage(sp,... while sp is your Sprite instance, not a sourceImage. Open up your dev tools console, remove all the errors there and come back only if there is one you can't remove, after having looked for it on the web first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple syntax errors in your code Just like @Kaiido pointed out:
`drawSprite(alSp[0][0]...`

also in the drawSprite, that should be:
`this.ctx.drawImage(sp.img,`

You have to reduce the size of your problems otherwise they will overwhelm you.
Here is a push in the right direction. I did converted the image to a base64 so everything runs in the snippet.

```js
function Screen(width, height) {
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.canvas.width = this.width = width;
    this.canvas.height = this.height = height;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
  };

  Screen.prototype.drawSprite = function(sp, x, y) {
    this.ctx.drawImage(sp.img, sp.x, sp.y, sp.w, sp.h, x, y, sp.w, sp.h);
  };

  function Sprite(img, x, y, w, h) {
    this.img = img;
    this.x = x;    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;    this.h = h;
  };

  var screen, frames, alSprite;
  function main() {
    screen = new Screen(510, 600);
    var img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener("load", function() {
      alSprite = [
        [new Sprite(this, 10, 10, 22, 15), new Sprite(this, 0, 16, 22, 16)],
      ];
      run();
    });
    img.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
  };

  function run() {
    screen.drawSprite(alSprite[0][0], 10, 10);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(run, screen.canvas);
  };
```

```html
<body onload="main()"></body>
```